# Share internet connection from virtual machine with host machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware, connection-sharing

Ok this is a little bit strange, I hope you will understand.

I have an internet stick, that only works in windows XP. My laptop is running Windows 7 64 bit. So I have set up vmware, with a windows xp virtual machine. I added and installed the usb internet stick, and I have internet inside my virtual machine.

Now I want to share this internet connection I have inside my virtual machine, with my host machine, the windows 7 laptop.

Does this make any sense to anyone, and if so, does anyone know a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if you set static IPs for both host and the VM network adapter, and set the VM IP as the default gateway on your host, it may work.
Can you try it and share the result here ?

Comment: OK I will try this. But do I use a host-only, bridged, or NAT connection. And I I set the ip's what should I fill in the preffred DNS section

Comment: Try Host-Only, it should work. And for the dns you can use google's public dns. It's 8.8.8.8

Comment: Sorry I tried it but I did not get it to work, I am horrible at this tcp IP stuff. I had it host-only, vm was 192.168.0.103 and gateway was 192.168.0.1, and for the host ip was 192.168.0.102 and gateway 192.168.0.103. Was this correct. Or can you maybe expand your answer with some concrete numbers I can fill in. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The result I got was that internet failed on both VM and Host. Internet connection sharing is enabled on the interface of the stick by the way, and the LAN connection does not have ICS option. Is this ok, or should I change this.

Comment: Hum okay. Yes because your VM now tries to get to 192.168.0.1 to access internet. And this IP doesn't exist.  
Yeah i'm not a TCP/IP expert either, but we can figure it out.  
On your VM you should have 2 network adapters : your usb stick, and a virtual network adapter. The host tries to contact the virtual network adapter, and then use the USB one to get to the internet.
Let's say. Try to configure your VM this way :  
ip : 192.168.1.10
mask : 255.255.255.0
gateway : none (because you're the gateway). By the way, you should be able to access internet on the VM anytime !

Comment: On your host, try this : ip 192.168.1.20
mask : 255.255.255.0 
gateway : 192.168.1.10

Comment: LOL, yes this method works great. I am actually sending this message from the windows 7 host. Nice, now I don;t have to work in the VM anymore! Thank you for the time man, I would have never figured this out by myself. Great work!